# Excel VBA Macro to Apply Conditional Formulas with Changing Named Ranges

Tags: vba, excel

I'm writing a macro that will add conditional formulas onto multiple worksheets which are titled Hazard 1/Hazard 2/Hazard 3/Hazard 4. It's set to loop through the worksheets, and each of the worksheets has their own named ranges where only the prefix changes (H1Ans1Rng, H2Ans1Rng, H3Ans1Rng, H4Ans1Rng, etc.). I need the code to write in a formula on each worksheet with the correct named ranges in place. I have a code that will do it, but it is bulky and now I am getting a "Procedure too large" error. The formulas the client gave me to apply are massive and much more complex than the example below.

```
    If Wks.Name = "Hazard 1" Then Rng.FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(H1Ans1Rng+H1Ans2Rng)"
    If Wks.Name = "Hazard 2" Then Rng.FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(H2Ans1Rng+H2Ans2Rng)"
    If Wks.Name = "Hazard 3" Then Rng.FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(H3Ans1Rng+H3Ans2Rng)"
    If Wks.Name = "Hazard 4" Then Rng.FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(H4Ans1Rng+H4Ans2Rng)"
```

Comment: There are too many ways of responding to this question without more information. For example, how do 4 worksheet formulas cause a 'Procedure too large' error? If you're using VBA why couldn't you calculate the answers within your code? Do you just need a string builder for the formula? Why are you using the R1C1 property? Is there is reason you haven't got a named range to worksheet map? If you could expand your question, it'd be easier for us to meet your needs.

Comment: Sorry, my question was the most simplified version of my question I could come up with, the code itself is massive. I was asked to create a worksheet that essentially you would choose the number of tabs that would need to be created (1-4), then Hazard 1-4 would populate based on the numbers. The way I had it set up worked well enough at first when it was small, but they keep asking to make it more complicated, so the code has gotten less than clean, hence the procedure errors. The answer below worked well enough though, I just now have to define a ton of variables for the formulas. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With some blind shots I'll go like follows

```
Dim hazardNr As String

hazardNr = Replace(Wks.Name, "Hazard ", "")
rng.Formula = "=SUM(H" & hazardNr & "Ans1Rng,H" & hazardNr & "Ans2Rng)" & ")"
```

Comment: That worked :) I've never been able to get it to work with variables in a formula but I guess I was just defining them wrong. Thank you!